# pandas pivot a DataFrame by multiple and dynamic columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to achieve something like below in a more sufficient way. I think df.pivot might do it, but I can't make it work. Any suggestions?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'level1':['a', 'a'], 'level2':['b', 'b'], 'level3':[100, 101], 'id1':[111,222],'id2':[333,444], 'foo_value':[0.1,0.2], 'bar_value':[0.3,0.4]})

# now i want to re-shape it to below
rows = []
items = [col.replace("_value", "") for col in df.columns if col.endswith("_value")]
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for id_col in ("id1", "id2"):
        for item in items:
            rows.append({
                "id": row[id_col],
                "item": item,
                "value": row[f"{item}_value"],
                "level1": row["level1"],
                "level2": row["level2"],
                "level3": row["level3"]
            })
reshaped_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)

```
l = ['level1', 'level2', 'level3']
s1 = df.melt(l, value_vars=df.filter(like='id'), value_name='id')
s2 = df.melt(l, value_vars=df.filter(like='_value'), var_name='item')

out = s1.merge(s2).drop('variable', axis=1)
```

Result

```
print(out)

  level1 level2  level3   id       item  value
0      a      b     100  111  foo_value    0.1
1      a      b     100  111  bar_value    0.3
2      a      b     100  333  foo_value    0.1
3      a      b     100  333  bar_value    0.3
4      a      b     101  222  foo_value    0.2
5      a      b     101  222  bar_value    0.4
6      a      b     101  444  foo_value    0.2
7      a      b     101  444  bar_value    0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You chose a hard way.

Try this:

```
df = df.T
df
```

It prints:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0X3s.png)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to transform to long form twice with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), using the `.value` placeholder ---> the `.value` determines which parts of the columns remain as headers:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['level*', '*value'], 
    names_to = '.value', 
    names_pattern ="(.+)\d")
.pivot_longer(
    index = ['level*', 'id'], 
    names_to = ('item', '.value'), 
    names_sep = '_')
)
  level1 level2  level3   id item  value
0      a      b     100  111  foo    0.1
1      a      b     101  222  foo    0.2
2      a      b     100  333  foo    0.1
3      a      b     101  444  foo    0.2
4      a      b     100  111  bar    0.3
5      a      b     101  222  bar    0.4
6      a      b     100  333  bar    0.3
7      a      b     101  444  bar    0.4
```